# How can I pull a list of page tags from a WordPress plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I created a plugin that pulls a list of tags from a page. If I load this as a shortcode, it functions fine, if I load this as a function in the plugin with add_action, it returns nada! Any ideas?

```
add_action( 'init', 'something_helper' );
function something_helper()
  {
     echo "the tags are: ".the_tags(); //returns nothing
  }
```

alternativly

```
function somefunction()
  {
     echo "the tags are: ".the_tags(); //returns tag list
  }
add_shortcode( 'shortcode_name', 'somefunction' );
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue I found was all in the load order. To fix this I loaded my function in the footer by changing:

```
add_action( 'init', 'something_helper' );
```

to

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'something_helper' );
```

After making this change, I was able to read my tags and even add conditions to my function by tag using `if(has_tag('tagname')){}`